# Post text/html using Jquery ajax in Tumblr?

Tags: jquery, tumblr, postdata

I registered my application in tumblr and want to post data from my web page . I used below java-script,but is doesn't seems to work even i am getting success message

```
<script>

    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/xxx.tumblr.com/posts/text?notes_info=true",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            api_key: "XYYYYYYY",
            title: "Milky Dog",
            body: "hi"
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error: function (response) { alert(0); }
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix the ajax post?

Answer (score 1):

I found one alternate solution for It.
Tumblr provide one unique email id for each user profile,I just e-mail my content to that unique ID and my post host on tumblr easily .

Go to setting Page and then ,click on last tab in navigation widget and check "Post by Email" .

Comment: Incase anyone needs further clarification about Post By Email: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/email_publishing